# how many managers for each employee?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got this query which selects the manager for each employee:

```
SELECT e1.Name EmployeeName, ISNULL(e2.name, 'Top Manager') AS ManagerName
FROM Employee e1
LEFT JOIN Employee e2
ON e1.ManagerID = e2.EmployeeID
```

I would like to have the number of managers for each employee. So for example Mike has 1 (Roger) and Marry has 2 ( David + Roger). How can I get this number for each row?

dbscript:

```
USE TempDb
GO
-- Create a Table
CREATE TABLE Employee(
EmployeeID INT PRIMARY KEY,
Name NVARCHAR(50),
ManagerID INT
)
GO
-- Insert Sample Data
INSERT INTO Employee
SELECT 1, 'Mike', 3
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'David', 3
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Roger', NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Marry',2
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Joseph',2
UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'Ben',2
GO
```

Comment: could you add a count(emp_name) in the select and then group by id

Comment: should roger be in the result too? (with count 0)?

Answer (score 1):

Please try using CTE:

```
;WITH T AS
(
    SELECT * FROM Employee 
    WHERE ManagerID IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.* FROM T
        INNER JOIN Employee a ON a.ManagerID =  T.EmployeeID
)
SELECT 
    Name, 
    COUNT(*) ManagerNumber 
FROM T 
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY 2, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e1.Name EmployeeName, count(NULLIF(e2.name, 'Top Manager')) Count_Manager
FROM Employee e1
LEFT JOIN Employee e2
ON e1.ManagerID = e2.EmployeeID
GROUP BY e1.Name
```

This is pseudo code, so try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...try this..

```
;with CTE1
as
(
    SELECT 0 AS MANAGERCOUNT,EmployeeID,MANAGERID,Name FROM #Employee WHERE MANAGERID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C.MANAGERCOUNT+1 AS MANAGERCOUNT,E.EmployeeID,E.MANAGERID,E.Name
    FROM #Employee E INNER JOIN CTE1 C ON C.EmployeeID = E.MANAGERID
)

SELECT * FROM CTE1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
;WITH    CTE
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        0 lvl
               FROM     @employee
               WHERE    ManagerID IS NULL
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   a.* ,
                        CASE WHEN a.ManagerID = b.EmployeeID THEN 1 + lvl
                             ELSE lvl
                        END
               FROM     @Employee a
                        INNER JOIN cte b ON a.ManagerID = b.EmployeeID
             )
    SELECT  EmployeeID ,
            name ,
            ManagerID ,
            lvl AS [No Of manager]
    FROM    cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-- Create a Table 
CREATE TABLE employee 
    ( 
         employeeid INT PRIMARY KEY,name NVARCHAR(50),managerid INT 
    ) 

go 

-- Insert Sample Data 
INSERT INTO employee 
SELECT 1,'Mike',3 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,'David',3 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 3,'Roger',NULL 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 4,'Marry',2 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 5,'Joseph',2 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 7,'Ben',2 

go 

WITH cte 
         AS (SELECT employeeid,name,managerid,Cast('Top Manager' AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS 
                                                                                         ManagerName,0 
                                        LVL 
                 FROM   employee 
                 WHERE  managerid IS NULL 
                 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT e.employeeid,e.name,e.managerid,c1.name ManagerName,c1.lvl + 1 
                 FROM   cte C1 
                                JOIN employee e 
                                    ON c1.employeeid = e.managerid) 
SELECT name,managername,lvl 
FROM   cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you would also like to show the top manager 'Roger' in the result set:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT * FROM Employee 
    WHERE ManagerID IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.EmployeeID, a.Name, a.ManagerID FROM CTE
        INNER JOIN Employee a ON a.ManagerID =  CTE.EmployeeID
)
SELECT Name, COUNT(*) COUNT_MANAGERS FROM CTE
GROUP BY Name
UNION ALL
SELECT Name, (SELECT 0) FROM Employee WHERE ManagerID IS NULL
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY COUNT_MANAGERS, Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
select t1.name, count(isnull(t2.name,'top mgr')) as CNTMGR 
 from Employee   t1 Join Employee  t2  On  t1.ManagerID=t2.EmployeeID 
GROUP BY t1.name
```